# Monaco editor: findNextMatch not working with new lines

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I'm currently working on IntelliSense for a custom language. I'm using the findNextMatch function from the ITextModel interface.

I want match a text containing new lines with a regex but the function doesn't work as expected. May be I did domething wrong and someone can help me.

I'm using this code :

```
const regex = /([^{]+)[ \t\r\n]*{|}/;
const nextMatch = model.findNextMatch(regex, currentPosition, true, true, null, true);
```

And I expect to capture the "grok" keyword or to match the last bracket depending on my cursor position:

```
grok 
{
     # Some code here
}
```

Actually, my regex work well on this example:

```
grok {
    # Some code
}
```

Comment: Looks like a problem with your regex, not a IntelliSense- or Monaco-specific thing...

Comment: I don't think `{|}` is valid regex... Can you give more examples of what you *expect* it to match?

Comment: My regex seems to be valid, I edited my post to add some explaination. Tell me if it is not enought to understand my problem.
I use this `{|}` to also match the bracket '}'. This is allow me to know if the cursor is inside two brackets or outside and to change the behavior of the Intellisense.

Comment: ohh, the `|` is an alternation. (english: "logical or")